# Excel formula, too long, there has to be an easier method

Tags: excel-formula, match

I have a simple table as below with 2 rows.

I'm trying to get the following 2 scenarios, I dont need to know the columns, just a true or false.

1. I want to know when column x has a number between 1 and 3 and the same column on the next row is between 1 and 2. Then I want to know when that match occurs at least 2 times.
2. I want to know when column x in the first and second rows = 1 and column y in the first and second rows = 2 and column z in the first and second rows = 3

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks in advance

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H | Column I | Column J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 4 |  |  |
|  |  |  | 2 |  | 1 | 3 |  |  |  |

Here is what I have done and it does work, I was just hoping there was an easier way. Just for reference I am using an offset, in this case RIGHT(P7,1)=1. Any help does not need to include the offset, I can put that back in.

1.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET(C$7,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0)),"",IF(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($C$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($C$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($D$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($D$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($E$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($E$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($F$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($F$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($G$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($G$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($H$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($H$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($I$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($I$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($J$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($J$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($K$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($K$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($L$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($L$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($M$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($M$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($N$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=3",OFFSET($N$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"<=2") >= 2, TRUE, FALSE))
```

2. 

```
=IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET(C$7,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0)),"",AND(IF(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($C$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($C$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($D$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($D$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($E$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($E$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($F$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($F$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($G$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($G$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($H$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($H$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($I$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($I$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($J$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($J$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($K$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($K$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($L$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($L$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($M$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($M$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($N$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1",OFFSET($N$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=1") = 1, TRUE, FALSE)
    ,
    IF(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($C$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($C$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($D$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($D$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($E$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($E$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($F$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($F$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($G$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($G$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($H$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($H$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($I$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($I$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($J$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($J$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($K$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($K$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($L$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($L$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($M$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($M$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($N$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2",OFFSET($N$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=2") = 1, TRUE, FALSE)
    ,
    IF(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($C$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($C$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($D$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($D$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($E$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($E$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($F$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($F$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($G$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($G$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($H$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($H$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($I$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($I$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($J$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($J$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($K$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($K$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($L$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($L$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($M$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($M$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") 
    + COUNTIFS(OFFSET($N$28,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3",OFFSET($N$29,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0),"=3") = 1, TRUE, FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

For 1:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A7:N7<=3)*(A8:N8<=2))>=2`

Example TRUE:
[image]

Example FALSE:
[image]

For 2:
`=(SUMPRODUCT((A7:N7=1)*(A8:N8=1))>=1)*(SUMPRODUCT((A7:N7=2)*(A8:N8=2))>=1)*(SUMPRODUCT((A7:N7=3)*(A8:N8=3))>=1)`

Or for 2 in Office 365 you could use `=AND(MAP(ROW(1:3),LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT((A7:N7=x)*(A8:N8=x))>=1)))`

*And for the (volatile) OFFSET, I want to discourage using that. `OFFSET(C$7,(26*RIGHT(P7,1)),0)` can be translated into `INDEX(C:C,7+26*RIGHT(P7,1))` for instance, which would result in the formula not recalculating at any change anywhere in the file.*

Comment: P.b, I tried out the suggestion and unfortunately it is not exactly correct. It looks like that will add up all the items in the range less than or equal to 3. Which will always be the same. What we need is to only add it if the cell below is also less than or equal to 2.

I did not try the others since I do not believe SUMPRODUCT will do what I want.

Comment: The sumproduct creates an array of true's and falses for the 2nd row less than or equal to 2 and an array of the 3rd row being less than or equal to 2. Multiplying these arrays makes sure that if either one or both of these arrays' condition is false it returns 0 from left to right (`0*0`, `0*1` or `1*0`) if both are true (`1*1`) it returns 1 from left to right. So if from left to right 2 or more columns meet the condition it returns true, else false.

Comment: Added screenshots to show the sumproduct formula with correct results

Answer (score 0):

Can you add rows at the top and copy the formula along?

criteria 1
=AND(C7>=1,C7<=3,C8>=1,C8<=2)

criteria 2
=AND(C7=1,C8=1,D7=2,D8=2,E7=3,E8=3)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's a good suggestion. I think I would prefer to use the longer equations though. This grid is just a snippet of a larger table. It wouldn't look right if I put that in and there are several iterations of it so it's not just hiding 2 rows to make it look better. It would be pretty involved to change the template, formulas, and macros. There are also 12 different equations this feeds into, so it would be 12 rows for each of these typically 8-10 per page.

Comment: With that said I could put it elsewhere on the page, like a scrap section off to the side, and achieve the same results but I think I still like the longer formulas. Really hoping there was a specific function that addressed this or different logic. (I have also tried using ands and ors with success, countifs were just easier and shorter.